# How to set yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores (number of virtual cores)

Tags: linux, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn, ambari

***I am little confuse***

What is the **yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores** value that should be ? ( based on the picture down ...)

1. real total CPU CORE on worker machine?

OR

2. set the value to 80% of real total CPU CORE on worker machine? 
    ( as some sites recommended )

for now I set it to 8 ( on each worker machine we have 8 CPU CORE )

example how to capture the "*real total CPU CORE*" on datanode machine:

```
nproc --all

8
```

***IMPORTANT REMARK*** - when I set it to 6 then it cause restarting spark thrift server , so I not have a choice and I set it to max - 8 , and now with 8 value its ok

[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @JWW  the other sites as super user or Linux & UNIX not have the tags for my question , so I am almost sure they cant answer on my question , stack overflow is the best site to deal with spark configuration